# Exclude some paths from Rack::Protection

Tags: ruby, csrf, rack

I want to use `Rack::Protection::JsonCsrf` only for a few paths, say `/user-login`. However I am not able to find an option related to this.

Can someone kindly point me to some example/documentation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? Show us some code where you've put some effort into it.

Comment: I have used  Rack::Csrf  instead.                                                         

`use Rack::Csrf, {:check_only=> ['POST:/user-login', 'POST:/restricted-view']}`